# Adding an item at an arbitrary location in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have the following array:

```
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
```

And I want to add the item `December` at position 11. From what I know I would do:

```
months.splice(11, 0, "December");
```

I would like it to be added in position 11 and positions 5 to 10 to be "null" or "undefined". However when I do:

```
months.indexOf("December")
```

I get a result of `5` and printing the array returns `December` as the last position right after June.

Is there a way to add this item at the specified position?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the index and assign the value. Unset items are `undefined`, because you got a sparse array.

```js
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June'];

months[11] = "December";

console.log(months.indexOf("December"));
console.log(months);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do is increase the array length and `push` the element.

```js
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'June'];

months.length = 11;
months.push("December");

console.log(months.indexOf("December"));
console.log(months.findIndex(x => x === "December"));
console.log(months);
```